# Merge ListBox & SuggestionBox

Tags: json, gwt, listbox, suggestbox

I have a ListBox in GWT which having the list of data which comes after the Parsing of JSON.

```
//ListBox test
private ListBox test;
test = new ListBox();
```

After Parsing the JSON data I am adding the data to the ListBox test.

```
JSONObject  userObj = val.isObject(); 
JSONArray userArray = JSONUtil.getJSONArray(userObj, "objects");
for (int i = 0; i < userArray.size(); i++) {
   JSONObject childJSONObject = (JSONObject) userArray.get(i);
   String userName = JSONUtil.getStringValue(childJSONObject, "name"); 
   test.addItem(userName);
 }
```

This works fine for Me. 
I want to merge it with SuggestionBox, same as like Browsers Navigation widget.
How can i implement this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean `SuggestBox` instead of `SuggestionBox`...

That said, if you want a `ListBox` that allows a user to type into it to select an entry, **take a look at [GwtChosen](https://github.com/ArcBees/gwtchosen)**.

It seems to have been created for this exact use case. You need a `ChosenListBox`:

[image: ChosenListBox]

Code samples and **documentation here**: http://jdramaix.github.io/gwtchosen/

Comment: Is it possible to do without plugin ?

Comment: For pure GWT, I think you can either have a `ListBox` or if you want the autocomplete-style search box you need a `SuggestBox` with a `MultiWordSuggestOracle`, which contains the possible options (instead of then being in ListBox). There is code here: http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~SuggestBox